# Phonegap build android generated app has no internet access from my computer ,whereas it works perfectly when build from other computer

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

In res/xml/config.xml has 
"access origin="*" "
The same project has a successful build from my other computer.
Above top of it,the app doesn't has location access in some mobiles when build from that other computer.
e.g: Xiaomi Note , whereas samsung phone has location access.

Comment: Are you using a code repository? Is everithing up to datw in there??

Comment: yes and the build is perfect from other computer